# How to write excel plugin in C# that calls C++ DLL exported function

Tags: c#, c++, excel, plugins, dll

I want to create an excel plug-in.
I have some C++ DLL that exports some functions defined in various classes.
I want to use these functions in creating excel plug-in.

For this I am trying to create a demo plugin that simly calculates simple interest.

This is below C++ DLL source file.

```
//SimpleInterest.CPP
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "CalSimpleInterest.h"

namespace simpleInt
{
    // total interest 
    double calculateInterest:: CalSimplInterest(double Principal, double Rate, double Time)
    {
        double interest = 0.0;
        interest = (Principal * Time * Rate) / 100;
        return interest;
    }
}
```

similary header file

```
//CalSimpleInterest.h
namespace simpleInt
{
    class calculateInterest
    {
        public:
        static __declspec(dllexport) double CalSimplInterest(double Principal, double Rate, double Time);
    };
}
```

I have complied and created CalSimpleInterest.dll .
Now I want to use CalSimplInterest() function in C#/C++ to create an excel plug-in.

I also searched various alternatives to write excel plug-in.

I found there are a number of ways to do this.

1. Make a C# wrapper that calls our unmanaged C++ code from .NET UDFs.
       -The .NET Framework provides PInvoke feature with the Dllimport attribute to allow managed applications to call unmanaged 
        functions packaged inside DLLs.
       -It has issues including speed, stability and skills.
2. Microsoft Excel SDK.
       - But I have read on various forums that it is a tedious and error-prone task that requires specialised skills and experience.
3. We can use as few third party additional frameworks/toolkits:

i) XLW (http://xlw.sourceforge.net/) that is a standard open-source C/C++ wrapper.

ii)The XLL+ toolkit hides the complexity of the environment and allows programmers and designers to concentrate on their core skills.

iii) For managed code, or to make a C# wrapper that calls your unmanaged C++ code from .NET UDFs, we can use Excel-DNA (http://exceldna.codeplex.com).

Please correct me if I am wrong about any of these method and suggest which method I can use out of these.

Comment: Search for C++/CLI or P/Invoke (Platform Invoke) on the Internet or SO.

Answer (score 1):

Using P/Invoke you can create class in C# that wrapps your native dll.

One tip - in your native dll implement functions within extern "C"{...} rather than class to avoid name mangling in output dll.

Native:

```
extern "C"
{
    static __declspec(dllexport) double CalSimplInterest(double Principal, double Rate, double Time)
    {
        double interest = 0.0;
        interest = (Principal * Time * Rate) / 100;
        return interest;
    }
}
```

C#:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class DllWrapper
{
    [DllImport("CalSimpleInterest.dll")]
    public static extern double CalSimplInterest(double Principal, double Rate, double Time);
}
```

More details can be found in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx.

Comment: But My native code is not C style. They are class methods in C++ dll. So How to use P/Invoke to create class in C# that wrapps for such native dll.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using .NET otherwise, I would not recommend you to add a C# wrapper to your C++ code. It's not clear that you gain anything from the added complexity.

If you are able to pay for a solution, I'd suggest you first consider the [Planatech XLL+ toolkit](http://www.as-ltd.co.uk/xllplus/default.htm) - it is well established, full featured and highly regarded for doing exactly what you are trying to do.

Otherwise, if you have some familiarity with the Excel C SDK and you're comfortable with modern C++ style, have a look at [Keith Lewis's xll add-in library](https://xll.codeplex.com/). He's got lots of examples and has implemented various advanced features, all with source code under a liberal license.

Finally, [XLW](http://xlw.sourceforge.net/index.shtml) which you mention is probably the standard open-source option for making C++ Excel add-ins.